# Problems Passing Parameters into SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcommand

I'm having problems passing parameters to a SQL string for a `SqlCommand`. When I use option 1 (see below), the code works. When I use option 2, it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to get the `.AddWithValue` method to work with the `SqlCommand`.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
private string [] GetOrderInfo (string folder)
{
    string [] order = new string [] { "date", "order#", "storeid", "storename", "username" };

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open ();

        // Option 1: this line works.
        //string sql = "select * from OrderProduct where OrderProductID=26846";

        // Option 2: this line doesn't work.
        string sql = "select * from OrderProduct where OrderProductID=@folder;";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sql, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@folder", folder);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader ())
            {
                while (reader.Read ())
                    order [1] = Convert.ToString (reader.GetInt32 (1));
            }
        }

        conn.Close ();
    } // using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (connectionString))

    return order;
}
```

Comment: In "option 1" you're assigning something that actually looks like a product ID: 26846.  In "option 2", you're assigning it a string called `folder`.  That doesn't seem to make sense...

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly.

Comment: The folder and OrderProductID are the same thing. OrderProductID is the field name in the database table, and it's also the name of the folder that is created for the order. I didn't set it up this way, it was done by company that built that app.

Comment: Try H. Fadlallah's answer.

Comment: Error is: SQL Exception unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@folder' to data type int.

Comment: `private string [] GetOrderInfo (int folder)`

Comment: This kind of problem is why [you really should avoid using AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@folder", int.Parse(folder));` will work, you need to pass the parameter value with correct type which database column type defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
 Command.Parameters.Add("@folder",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = folder;
```

Answer (score 1):

**AddWithValue** method uses the type of value to define the correct **SqlDbType**. So, if your field **OrderProductID** is type of **INT**, you need to add an **int**.

Sample:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@folder", 26846);
```

Another easy way is to use a Simple Object Mapper like [SqlDatabaseCommand](https://github.com/Apps72/Dev.Data) or [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

```
using (var cmd = new SqlDatabaseCommand(_connection))
{
    cmd.CommandText.AppendLine(" SELECT * ")
                   .AppendLine("   FROM EMP ")
                   .AppendLine("  WHERE EMPNO = @EmpNo ")
                   .AppendLine("    AND HIREDATE = @HireDate ");

    cmd.Parameters.AddValues(new
            {
                EmpNo = 7369,
                HireDate = new DateTime(1980, 12, 17)
            });

    var emps = cmd.ExecuteTable<Employee>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from OrderProduct where OrderProductID=@folder", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@folder", folder));

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            order[1] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see it was deprecated ? No mention here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx